# jQuery - JavaScript regex allow only numeric and minus sign as first character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want users to enter numeric values only in my input hence I put below code.

`<input type="text" class="form-control rounded-pill bg-light" autocomplete="off" name="free_credit_amount" id="free_credit_amount" placeholder="Free credit amount">`

```
$('body').on('keyup', '#free_credit_amount', function(){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
```

This is working fine for me .. however I have a requirement that, users can enter negative values as well .. something like `-500`
, hence I have updated my JavaScript Regex a bit with something like following ..

```
$('body').on('keyup', '#free_credit_amount', function(){   
   this.value = this.value.replace(/[^-0-9]/g,'');
});
```

This is also working fine for me as I am able to type `minus (-)` sign and can enter a value something like `500` or `-500` however, I want to furnish this regex a bit .. Currently what is happening, I can also enter a value like `500-`. This should not be allowed .. I only want my `minus (-)` to be only added as first character..

I have tried to use various other REGEX like `this.value = this.value.replace(/(\+|\-)?[^-0-9]/g,'');` `this.value = this.value.replace(/^[-][a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]/g,'');`

But none of those REGEX working for me ..

Can someone help me to achieve this plz ..

Thanks

Comment: Try `this.value.replace(/[^-0-9]+/g,'').replace(/^(-)|-+/g,'$1')`

Comment: The problem with this kind of interference with the user input, is that the user may get the impression that their keyboard is broken. They also wonder why sometimes the caret, which they had moved to the start of the input, suddenly moves to the end. This is not user-friendly at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
$('body').on('input', '#free_credit_amount', function(){
    var position = this.selectionStart;
    var oldval = this.value;
    var newval = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace(/^(-)|-+/g,'$1').replace(/^([^.]*\.)|\.+/g, '$1');
    this.value = newval;
    if (oldval != newval) {
        this.selectionEnd = position-1;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control rounded-pill bg-light" autocomplete="off" name="free_credit_amount" id="free_credit_amount" placeholder="Free credit amount">
```

Here,

- `.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '')` - removes all chars other than digits, dots and hyphens
- `.replace(/^(-)|-+/g,'$1')` - keeps the hyphen at the start of the string and removes all other hyphens
- `.replace(/^([^.]*\.)|\.+/g, '$1')` - keeps any amount of text other than `.` and the first `.`, and removes all other dots in the string

Comment: Magnificent .. Thank you .. Worked like a charm.