# input type number disable user being able to type multiple minus sign

Tags: html, reactjs

why input type number allow -- as input.

I want to disable it.

also it allow several cases like

-12-12

--

-121-

23-323-

Comment: Use Regular expression to overcome such scenario

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - JavaScript regex allow only numeric and minus sign as first character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597618/jquery-javascript-regex-allow-only-numeric-and-minus-sign-as-first-character)

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this same thing in my one of the project...

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    // Remove any leading or trailing whitespace
    const newValue = event.target.value.trim();
    
    // Validate the input using a regular expression
    const validInputPattern = /^-?\d*$/; // This allows for optional negative sign and digits
    
    if (validInputPattern.test(newValue)) {
      setInputValue(newValue);
    }
  };
```

.

```
    <div>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install **react-numeric-input** library in your project.

`npm install react-numeric-input`
Use this tag
`<NumericInput/>` This will work as simple input field.

Answer (score -1):

The `input type="number"` behavior you described, where it allows multiple minus signs and unexpected input patterns, is due to browser inconsistencies. To prevent this, use `input type="text"` and add JavaScript validation to restrict input to numbers and enforce desired formatting rules.

Html

```
<input type="text" id="numericInput" pattern="-?\d*\.?\d+" title="Please enter a valid number" />
```

JavaScript

```
const numericInput = document.getElementById('numericInput');

numericInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '');  // Remove non-numeric characters except minus and dot
  this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1'); // Remove extra dots
  this.value = this.value.replace(/^-/g, '');         // Remove leading minus signs
  this.value = this.value.replace(/-+/g, '-');       // Replace multiple minus signs with a single minus
});
```